# How to append element to each vector in a matrix - Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 500x2 matrix which has been filled using `numpy.random.rand`.

The output looks like this (but obviously a larger version):

```
 [ -3.28460744e+00  -4.29156493e-02]
 [ -1.90772015e-01  -9.17618367e-01]
 [ -2.41166994e+00  -3.76661496e+00]
 [ -2.43169366e+00  -6.31493375e-01]
 [ -1.48902305e+00  -9.78215901e-01]
 [ -3.11016192e+00  -1.87178962e+00]
 [ -3.72070031e+00  -1.66956850e+00]
```

I want to append `1` to the end of each row so that each line would look like this:

```
[ -3.72070031e+00  -1.66956850e+00  1]
```

Is this possible? I've been trying to use `numpy.append()` but struggling to work out what should be used.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `np.append(arr, np.ones((500, 1)), axis=-1)`

Comment: Thanks @Eric! But does this not return an array filled with 1s?

Comment: Why would you expect it to return an array full of ones?

Comment: @Eric Oh sorry I wasn't thinking at all there! That worked fantastically - thank you!

Comment: @Eric is there a way to do something similar to append any number? Say if I wanted to append a 3 instead?

Comment: Study and practice using `np.concatenate`.  That is the base for all the stack and append functions.

Comment: Hint: `one * 3 == 3`. Also, `one + 2 == 3`.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = np.ones((4,2)) * 2
>>> a
array([[ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.]])
```

[Numpy.concatenate documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate):
`The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis` ... `along which the arrays will be joined.`

```
>>> a.shape
(4, 2)
```

You want to concatenate along the second axis so make an array of ones that has a shape of (4,1) - use values from `a.shape` to do this.

```
b = np.ones((a.shape[0], 1))

>>> b.shape
(4, 1)
>>> b
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Now you can concatenate

```
z = np.concatenate((a,b), axis = 1)

>>> z
array([[ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Or use [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)

```
>>> np.hstack((a,b))
array([[ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  1.]])
```